# pandas filter row null and

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"months":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "value":[12,123,np.nan,234,345,456]})
```

I wanted to check for specific months(such as 0, 1, 3) any value is null or 0

I tried to do following way but does not work

```
if my_df[(my_df["months"].isin([0, 1, 3])) & (my_df["value"].isnull() | my_df["value"] == 0)].empty:
```

this still gives output as **True**

Comment: I want to check value for months 0,1,3 is not Nan or 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the "not" `~` part while checking for null values. Try this instead:

```
>>> my_df[(my_df["months"].isin([0,1,3])) & ~(my_df["value"].isnull()|my_df["value"]==0)]
   months  value
0       0   12.0
1       1  123.0
3       3  234.0
```

With your `empty` check:

```
>>> my_df[(my_df["months"].isin([0,1,3])) & ~(my_df["value"].isnull()|my_df["value"]==0)].empty
False
```

### Edit:

To check if *any* value for the given months is not zero or null, you could do:

```
>>> any((my_df["months"].isin([0,1,2]))&((my_df["value"].isnull())|(my_df["value"]==0)))
True
```

Comment: but if I change months and add 2 it give me the wrong output as **False** again
`>>> my_df[(my_df["months"].isin([0, 1, 2])) & ~(my_df["value"].isnull()|my_df["value"]==0)].empty`

Comment: The output should be False. You have rows `(0, 12)` and `(1, 123)` which have months in `[0, 1, 2]` where the values are not null. What do you expect?

Comment: Oh, apologies (Changed the question removed not), I mean to say if any of given months have null or 0 values then I need to log them in error

Comment: @RachanaMahajan - Edited